# Remove white space in table

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a table and in one of the columns exists two icons.
here is the pic

[image]

this is the code:

```html
<td>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus-circle-o text-success"></i>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-help zmdi-hc-fw" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-container="body" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="ADD"></i>
</td>
```

I need the icons to be in the same line and the same height as the other icons.
So I added `display: flex`.
And get this result:

[image]

And since I need the icons to be in the same line as the other I used:
`padding-top: 23px` and get this results

[image]

The problem is when I hover with the mouse on the line, in this place exists the white or blank space.
The white space starts exactly after I used display flex, and reduces a little after I used padding top.
I do not want this white blank, so when I hover all the line will be blue as before (first pic).
can someone assist

this is my new code:

```
<td style="display: flex;padding-top: 23px;">
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus-circle-o text-success"></i>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-help zmdi-hc-fw" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-container="body" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="ADD"></i>
</td>
```

this is the computed tab
[image]

If I do this in the developer tools it solved, how to do it via code?
[image]

Comment: this is the relevant code, it worked fine before the flex, I added the computed tab pic

Comment: <td style="display: flex;padding-top: 23px;">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus-circle-o text-success"></i>
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-help zmdi-hc-fw" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-container="body" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="ADD"></i>
                
</td>

Comment: not in comments, do you know how to do it? it's not enough, post the related css and html code

Comment: sorry I can not provide more info, this is the line that I changed this is the css inline

Comment: @Bastian can you make a minimum reproducible snippet to show this though?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look, I have created an example and it works, so you should check CSS code.

If you cannot provide CSS code how can I help?

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="display: flex;">
         <i style="width: 25px;height: 25px;border: 1px solid blue;display: unset;"
            class="zmdi zmdi-plus-circle-o text-success"></i>
         <i style="width: 25px;height: 25px;border: 1px solid blue;display: unset;"
            class="zmdi zmdi-help zmdi-hc-fw" 
            data-toggle="tooltip" 
            data-placement="top" 
            data-container="body" 
            data-html="true" title="" 
            data-original-title="ADD">
         </i>           
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I do not want to touch the icons. no css no css file exists no css I want to do it inline just to remove the white space

Comment: sorry not working. I do not understand why display flex do this whitespace, I can not compute it or remove it, or do it transparent.

Comment: but the problem is not the icons the problem is the white space. the blue is just when the mouse over. I need a way that the element td will be as before all the height. now it is just 75% of the row

Comment: @Bastian try to add `style="display: flex;flex-direction: row` in `td`. Can I access the site? I cannot guess what it's causing the issue.

Comment: no sorry, but I have a small progress maybe you can advise. in the <i tags if I remove in the developer tools the display: inline block, it solved it. the problem is that I do not know how to do it via code. I will add what I have done to the original question that you can see

Comment: @Bastian you can unset it using `style="display: unset;"` if still not working use `display: unset !important;` my answer updated.

Comment: if you don't want the icon to touch add a padding or a gap to the elements :)

Comment: sometimes it worked sometimes not, I do not understand the developer tools.

Comment: yes in some places it worked and in other not,

Comment: this is the problem sometimes if I remove via the developer tools the display:inline block it worked and sometimes not, I can not find any logic